# PHP - Read more page returns 'undefined variable' error

Tags: php, sql

I've been working on a 'read more' page for quite a while now. What I basically want is when you click read more, it will redirect to the news item page.

Index.php

```
$p=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, titel, tekst, datum FROM nieuws LIMIT $start, $limit");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($p) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
          $nieuws = $row['0'];

          echo "<h2>".$row['1']."</h2>";
          echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
          echo "<p>".$row['2']."</p>";
          echo "<p> Geplaatst op: ".$row['3']."</p>";
          echo "<a href='pages/nieuws.php?nieuwsitem=$nieuws'>Lees meer..</a></br></br>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Geen items gevonden.";
      }
```

nieuws.php

```
<?php
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "groenevingers");

      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

      $p=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, titel, tekst, datum FROM nieuws WHERE id='$nieuws'");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($p) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
          echo "<h2>".$row['1']."</h2>";
          echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
          echo "<p>".$row['2']."</p>";
          echo "<p> Geplaatst op: ".$row['3']."</p>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Item niet gevonden.";
      }
    ?>
```

In 'nieuws.php' it should display the specific news item with the id. However, I get an error saying 'Notice: Undefined variable: nieuws '.
I can understand why it says that error because i haven't defined a $row['0'] which is my news id in my news table but i can't solve it somehow.

Is there anyway you guys could help me out? 
Help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
vaxzz

Comment: These are two separate files, so you need to define your Variable before you can use it

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought allready, but I can't seem to fix it. As you see i defined $nieuws to $row['0'] in the index.php, when i do exactly the same in nieuws.php i get the error: 'Undefined variable: row'.

Comment: This is not the first time this topic has been covered please look at `pagination with mysqli`. Also look at preventing SQL injections with parameterized queries.

Comment: Probably because row isn't defined in that moment either.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner PHP. I haven't been able to spend time in preventing SQL injections, i'll do this at a later point. How would one go about defining row then Fabian Bettag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to change your code for your newspage like this:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "groenevingers");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    if(isset($_GET['nieuwsitem'])) {
        $nieuws = intval($_GET['nieuwsitem']);
        $p=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, titel, tekst, datum FROM nieuws WHERE id='$nieuws'");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($p) > 0) {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
                echo "<h2>".$row['1']."</h2>";
                echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
                echo "<p>".$row['2']."</p>";
                echo "<p> Geplaatst op: ".$row['3']."</p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Item niet gevonden.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Item niet gevonden.";
    }  
?>
```

This will do several things:

```
if(isset($_GET['nieuwsitem'])) {
```

checks if there's an ID in your URL

```
$nieuws = intval($_GET['nieuwsitem']);
```

Retrieves that ID and also converts it into an integer, so it's "safe" to use in your query, also it sets your `$nieuws` variable

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works great now. I knew I had to use isset but haven't used intval before (Beginner in PHP). Yet again, thank you for the help, it's greatly appreciated and learned something new =)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable $nieuws before you use it:
nieuws.php:-

```
 <?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "groenevingers");

 $nieuws = $_GET['nieuwsitem'];

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $p=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, title, text, datum FROM nieuws WHERE id='$nieuws'");

 if(mysqli_num_rows($p) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
  echo "<h2>".$row['1']."</h2>";
  echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
  echo "<p>".$row['2']."</p>";
  echo "<p> Geplaatst op: ".$row['3']."</p>";
}
} else {
  echo "Item niet gevonden.";
 }
?>
```